# JavaFx barchart categorygap

Tags: java, javafx, bar-chart, dynamic-data

I have a barchart which represents dynamic data.

In case of only single item the bar width was too wide hence I included a conditional loop in which if there was a single item, I have used barchart1.setCategoryGap(500).

But the problem I am facing is that once this method is called ,the categorygap is set 500 even for more than one item.
I want to know how I can again set it default (calculated internally).